Dockware Shopware 6 not auto reloading storefront
When I'm running in the dockware container make watch-storefront, I can access localhost:9998, refreshing manually shows me the changes but it doesn't reload automatically. In the console I'm getting this error: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9999/ws' failed
Anyone has a clue? Am I missing something or do I need to provide more information?
Browser: Google Chrome (v127.0.6533.120)
Device: Apple Macbook Pro (M1 Pro chip)
Error of the console log
Dockware config:
services:

  shopware:
    image: dockware/dev:6.6.1.0
    container_name: shopware
    ports:
      - "22:22"     # ssh
      - "82:80"     # apache2
      - "444:443"   # apache2 https
      - "8888:8888" # watch admin
      - "9998:9998" # watch storefront proxy
      - "9999:9999" # watch storefront
      - "3307:3306" # mysql port
    networks:
      - web
    volumes:
      - "./src/vendor:/var/www/html/vendor"
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_ENABLED=1
networks:
  web:
    external: false

Searched Google but no information found

did you solve the problem?
